# How to disable weak cipher suit without affecting the website

Tags: iis, encryption, windows-server-2012-r2

SSL Server Test for my website shows weak cipher suite for followings. It would be great , if anyone could give an advice to hardening the web server.

Windows Server 2012 R2
IIS 8.5

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS WEAK 256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS WEAK 128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA    (0xc014) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS WEAK 256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA    (0xc013) ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA) FS WEAK 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       (0x9d)                                          WEAK 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256       (0x9c)                                          WEAK 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256       (0x3d)                                          WEAK 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256       (0x3c)                                          WEAK 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA          (0x35)                                          WEAK 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA          (0x2f)                                          WEAK
```

I have disabled the weaker suits but the site stopped working.

Comment: You have to choose between allowing weak cipher suites and rejecting old clients that don't support at least one of the strong cipher suites. Changing the TLS configuration always affects clients, so your question cannot be answered. Your best bet is to disable cipher suites one by one and check if the client(s) you care about are still supported by looking at the handshake simulation. Afterwards try to get your hands on actual clients and verify.